# Phpmyadmin is not working in openshift

Tags: openshift

I'm using Open shift for hosting my database

for the last 3 month everything was working 
and I could access Phpmyadmin from the open shift console

now I can not access :
[https://myappname.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/](https://*myappname*.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/)

the page is not loading after I click on the phpMyAdmin 4.0 cartridge in the console

even though I can still use the database (MySQL 5.5)

Comment: Have you checked your log files?

Comment: What does happen? Do you get an error page, blank page, partially loaded page, does it keep reloading the same page, etc? Do you get a login prompt?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch page isn’t working , HTTP error 500

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves where can i see the log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the console
https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications

and restart the application.

The most times this fixes.